# "The connection has timed out" issue for a website from my router

Tags: internet-connection

I'm unable to access the website (www.5pillarsgame.com) from my home router.

I thought that this problem would be from the server side but strange thing is that it is working on other networks! I have tried to access it through IE, chrome,FF, Opera, Safari, even tried from other PCs from my internet connection but no success.
Does anyone have any idea why is this happening so?

Comment: Firewall filtering on router? Try changing DNS server and bypass the router. Check if you can traceroute to this www site. Try to access it via web proxy like hidemyass.com and see if it works. Check `netstat -a -n` command while trying to connect to see if you got the connection in hanging SYN_SENT state or is it in different state.

Comment: Tried web prxoy, works there. 'netstat' is giving me SYN_SENT. Tried traceroute, looked up the ip on whois and got the following
_ERROR:201: access denied 
 Queries from your IP address have passed the daily limit of controlled objects.Access from your host has been temporarily denied._

Comment: You got a SYN_SENT status when connecting which means the router/firewall/ISP proxy(if exist) is not sending your SYN packet to the server or the SYN+ACK packet that should be sent to you from server is blocked when reaching the firewall from the outside. Either way this is configured on the firewall level. Especially since everything works via web proxy.

Comment: So what will be the next course of action?

Comment: examine the firewall rules and if you will not find anything suspicious contact your ISP.